How to pass a specific parameter to my dataset
I have DataTable as a result of executing a stored procedure. The stored procedure is returning a number of tables, therefore Tables[0], Tables[1], etc.
I'm trying to query the first table, Tables[0], to find rows that have column Id equal to the value of a parameter id that needs to passed in.
private static DataSet _dataTable;   // populated from a stored procedure call

DataRow[] siteTable = _dataTable.Tables[0].Select("[Id] = " + id);

However that DataRow[] siteTable does not have any value in it, even though the value for id does exist.

What type has Id?

Is this a linq Select? The last time i used it it has a Syntax more like .Select(id => "[Id] = " + id);
